# Need to drain boiler expansion tank but no drain valve

Tags: boiler

Been having intermittent banging during heating season. It happens around once a month and the whole house shakes. The gas company believes that it's a bad expansion tank. The old-style expansion tank is probably a 20-25 gallon one. that needs to be drained but there's no drain valve, only unions. Do I need to break the unions in order to drain it or can I just empty it by draining the boiler down?

Comment: pictures and diagrams always help as well as a list of the components of your heating system.   One more comment, at my church we had an old gas boiler that was having ignition problems. Every once in a while, unignited gas would build up and eventually get "ignited" with a loud boom.  The boiler has since been replaced, so no worries there. Just mentioning this in case it may help.   I don't know enough about expansion tanks, but it seems odd that it could cause what you are experiencing.

Comment: The "banging" could be water hammer issues.  Is there a place to attach a bike pump to your expansion tank? (Modern expansion tanks have such a fitting, universally)

Comment: I tend to agree that if the tank bladder/diaphragm had failed, and the system was prone to water-hammer, you would experience the issue more often than 1x per month.